# How to define cost function for custom nonlinear functions?

Tags: neural-networks, logistic, loss-functions

For logistic regression, the ***Cost*** function is defined as:
\begin{equation}
Cost(h_{\theta}(x)-y) = -ylog(h_{\theta}(x))-(1-y)log(1-h_{\theta}(x))
\end{equation}

I now have a nonlinear function
\begin{equation}
 h_{\theta}^{(i)}(x)=xe^{-j\theta_i|x|^2}
\end{equation}
where $i$ denotes the $i$th training sample. How should I define cost function for this particular nonlinear function?

Comment: Why would you define it any different? What problem do you hope to solve with this nonlinear regression?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I realised that I misunderstood the problem that time. The activation function was different but the cost function was MSE. Should I close this?

Comment: You might consider posting a self-answer where you explain what you’ve realized.

Comment: Great, thank you very much

Comment: Also, what is $j$ in your $h^i_{\theta}$ equation? I k own some fields use $j=\sqrt{-1}$, but that does not appear to be what you mean. // Does your $h$ function output values between zero and one? If that breaks down, the usual logistic regression log loss is undefined, since the function is outputting impossible probability values. Does your $h$ only output possible probability values?

Comment: Yes, $j$ is the imaginary unit in the equation, and the nonlinear function is supposed to model the physical fibre model regarding a nonlinear phase change.

Comment: What kind of outputs are you hoping to get from your complex-values regression equation? Do you have complex measurements? // I see multiple issues with the question that I did not see last month. What is your goal, why are you modeling with this particular equation, what does the equation mean, and how does the logistic regression log loss play a part in your work?

Comment: An imaginary number in the form of a+bj converted to a real 2d vec [a, b].

Comment: Please say more about what you want to do and what your model means. It is not clear how to interpret your $h$ function, particularly the subscript on $\theta_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Cost function $Cost$ computes the cost between the **output** of a parameterised model $f_{\theta}(x)$ including neurons with a customised activation function  $h_{\theta}(x)$ or a parameterised function $h_{\theta}(x)$ & ground truth $y$. It is independently defined from $h_{\theta}(x)$. In other words, one can define any cost function for any functions as long as the output and ground truth are obtained.

Comment: I’m not a downvoter, but it is not clear to me why this answers the question. Could you please expand the answer to explain why this answers the question? I’d imagine this is what has caused members to downvote.

Comment: Haha no worries about the downvotes. Thank you for your feedback, I'll work on the elaboration.

Comment: This revision does much to improve the quality of this answer. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!